# Cypher: What are the performance implications with a large nested WHERE/CONTAINS clause?

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher, query-optimization

Im using queries that have large WHERE clauses:

```
WHERE (
        (n.val CONTAINS 'wrd1-1' AND n.val CONTAINS 'wrd1-2' AND n.val CONTAINS 'wrd1-3') OR
        (n.val CONTAINS 'wrd2-1' AND n.val CONTAINS 'wrd2-2' AND n.val CONTAINS 'wrd2-3') OR
        (n.val CONTAINS 'wrd3-1' AND n.val CONTAINS 'wrd3-2' AND n.val CONTAINS 'wrd3-3') OR
        .
        .
        .

        (n.val CONTAINS 'wrd20-1' AND n.val CONTAINS 'wrd20-2' AND n.val CONTAINS 'wrd20-3')
      )
```

n.val is a string of words and I wish to match tri-grams (wrd). I'm using CONTAINS for word-order **independence**

1. Is there a better way to do this in Cypher?
2. Would an RDBMS deal with this better?

Answer (score 2):

Speaking purely for simplifying the Cypher query itself (not necessarily the performance), if you can gather the words you want to search for into lists of lists, then your query can be stable no matter how many words or how many sets.

Here's an example:

```
// below for example input, though you would want to parameterize this
WITH [['wrd1-1', 'wrd1-2', 'wrd1-3'], ['wrd2-1', 'wrd2-2', 'wrd2-3'], ['wrd3-1', 'wrd3-2', 'wrd3-3']] as searchData
MATCH (n:Node) // or whatever type you're matching on
UNWIND searchData as words
WITH n 
WHERE all(word IN words WHERE n.val CONTAINS word) 
RETURN n
```

The last WHERE clause using the `all()` predicate function will ensure that the CONTAINS check must hold true on that node for all of the words in the collection.

As far as performance goes, you mentioned that you're using CONTAINS for word-order independence. If the `val` property only contains whole words, and your goal is to only lookup on whole words in the property, then there are a couple different ways you can handle this.

If the number of words currently in the `val` property is the same number you'll be searching on (always 3 words, for example, where you'll always be searching for those same 3 words), then you could refactor your data so that `val` is always alphabetically ordered and lowercase, then index the property, so that when you perform a lookup you can change your input to the same format (lowercase and alphabetical) and perform an exact lookup, which will leverage the index.

If you need to be able to query for a subset of the words on the node (but you're still only looking for whole words only), then you might consider refactoring your data so that instead of a `val` property on your nodes, words become their own nodes with relationships to the original nodes.

That way, you can perform index lookup to the :Word nodes, and from there match to nodes that have relationships to all of the :Word nodes you matched to.

Heres an [article on performing match intersection](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/performing-match-intersection/) that explains a few approaches to those kind of matches.